# Vue reactiviy loop?

Tags: vuejs3, watch

I'm still very new to Vue and reactivity but I seem to have got myself into a bit of a mess.

I have written a simple composable called `remoteSearch.js` to run a search with Algolia. The `query` parameter is reactive and I have a watcher to check when it changes to instantly rerun the search. (I've had to disable the actual call and fake the data temporarily while I solve this problem).

I'm using this is a Component that needs to covert the response from an Array to a Object when both key and value are an element from the array e.g. [1,2,3] => {1:1,2:2,3:3}. It's this that seems to be causing me the problem.

My remoteSearch.js:

```
import { ref, watch } from 'vue';
import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch/lite';

export function remoteSearch(indexName, attribute, query) {

  console.log('remote search triggered');

  const results = ref([]);

  const searchClient = algoliasearch(
    import.meta.env.VITE_ALGOLIA_APP_ID,
    import.meta.env.VITE_ALGOLIA_SEARCH
  );

  const index = searchClient.initIndex(indexName);


  watch(query, async(newQuery, oldQuery) => {
    try{

      // faking call to Algolia temporarily
      const res =  await {
        "hits": [
          {
            "tag": "tag",
            "objectID": "433",
            "_highlightResult": {
              "tag": {
                "value": "<em>Match</em>",
                "matchLevel": "partial"
              },
            }
          }
        ],
        "page": 0,
        "nbHits": 1,
        "nbPages": 1,
        "hitsPerPage": 20,
        "processingTimeMS": 1,
        "query": newQuery.value
      };

      results.value = res.hits.map((hit) => hit[attribute]);

      console.log(crypto.randomUUID() + ' - query:' + query.value);

    } catch (error) {

      console.log('error');

    }
  })

  return(results);
}
```

The parent Component:

```
<script setup>

    import {computed, ref} from 'vue';
    import {remoteSearch} from '@/composables/remoteSearch.js';

    const props = defineProps({
        modelValue : {
            type: [String, null],
            required: true
        },
        index : {
            type: String,
            required : true
        },
        attribute : {
            type: String,
            required : true
        }
    })

    const query = ref();

    const results = computed(() => {

        const res = remoteSearch(props.index,props.attribute,query);

        return  Object.assign({},res.value);   //<-- Culprit

    });


</script>
<template>

    <input type="text" v-model="query">

    {{ results }}



</template>
```

I then enter 1,2,3,4 slowly and then delete each slowly. Here is my console:

```
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:7 remote search triggered
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 4627fb07-c2dc-4828-b84d-e33cd3ad782d - query:1
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:7 remote search triggered
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 0fffe218-1e00-49e6-accd-cee0dcb83e09 - query:12
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 ef9b6fc5-e779-43a6-886e-209acbe02606 - query:12
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:7 remote search triggered
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 1c84bed2-72a9-48d2-9a89-029d215c3290 - query:123
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 eee5e04c-9be3-4671-be1b-8df0e2996f23 - query:123
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 881017d7-71a8-4332-b92f-cbf722eca39c - query:123
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:7 remote search triggered
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 9e4e6c55-3705-4f18-8136-c3316b4bfdcc - query:1234
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 07f3471e-d308-4738-af07-812a7e492f5d - query:1234
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 f02e54f0-5039-4e91-960e-902637326c18 - query:1234
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 f28aa419-8535-4bc1-8f53-b1a1019962d5 - query:1234
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:7 remote search triggered
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 c7bacf65-273e-4783-830b-919cc4854c43 - query:123
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 532b079a-eab8-4b25-b0a6-14273e170ef3 - query:123
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 511ea1d5-4351-401b-99af-8b7be45b0b2a - query:123
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 bd2c5d09-2760-4a56-8342-196d210e7e13 - query:123
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 f38c6dd9-d072-46e9-ae04-8390c403cf2b - query:123
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:7 remote search triggered
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 3da18b71-8151-48c4-b436-be6bcd5f3e07 - query:12
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 9fea3f33-d230-43c8-b246-9a287a210fd8 - query:12
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 579c0d40-19a9-4952-92e2-78674f4a2327 - query:12
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 bb8eaf0b-2673-488b-aaf4-84f86961be05 - query:12
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 0fe64241-10fa-4a25-915d-ac354b13e005 - query:12
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 a213f25c-70ef-4d8b-b772-6ffb617d8bcd - query:12
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:7 remote search triggered
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 be110868-8da6-432d-980e-219b510245ba - query:1
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 fe3e69fb-04bb-472a-9395-04c0ff36ae84 - query:1
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 db2e2f4d-d5b7-4f33-bce0-36fe355849dd - query:1
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 8875c64a-fec3-43fc-b461-19c3404b4148 - query:1
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 e9107902-9f04-4cb4-ba20-5e4efcafc6c5 - query:1
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 e90bfb73-5c7e-4d4e-af1c-6128027bed7c - query:1
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 f2e84d62-857a-4069-b5e5-c557913bb2d1 - query:1
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:7 remote search triggered
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 fbfb2ef9-2fd0-4323-bd8b-f1f182b3912e - query:
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 88686694-b793-4e66-9fdc-a9024070aa13 - query:
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 794e7e9d-7cc3-4412-aa2c-31d3354152e2 - query:
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 21e54b2e-1b4e-4133-b266-07c63f477bd8 - query:
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 430b53c9-385e-4add-b83e-7d20bdce7ef1 - query:
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 36f4ccd4-ecad-4126-8d1a-41afafcf0a6d - query:
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 d6654c87-97bb-4b45-935d-7ffd2c62818f - query:
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:46 239d908c-3250-4780-a0e5-9311ff3e676a - query:
remoteSearch.js?t=1689319961898:7 remote search triggered
```

Comment: I can tell you this much that binding refs and watchers (from remoteSearch) inside a computed property is a wrong approach with Vue, so the problem could lie there. the search fn should already return a reactive value, so you don't need it in computed. You could do `const results = remoteSearch(props.index,props.attribute,query)` and it should be reactive since you're returning a ref

Comment: @SamuelEiche thanks for your reply! You are so right and  I'm almost annoyed it was so simple but thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, every call to `remoteSearch()` creates a new watcher, so every time `query` changes, all existing watchers are triggered and a new one is added through the computed.

Also, note that the result from `Object.assign({},res.value);` is not bound to the reactive `res`. When the search finishes and `res` is updated, the new object will not reflect these changes.

I would suggest to write your composable as an init function, where you pass in reactive arguments and you only call it once, while your computed works on the returned reactive property:

```
const query = ref();
const searchResults = useRemoteSearchResult(toRef(props, 'index'), toRef(props, 'attribute'), query)
const results = computed(() => Object.assign({},res.value))
```

Looks like all you have to change in your composable is to move `index` into the watcher, and instead of watching only `query`, watch all arguments:

```
export function useRemoteSearchResult(indexName, attribute, query) {
  const results = ref([]);

  const searchClient = algoliasearch(
    import.meta.env.VITE_ALGOLIA_APP_ID,
    import.meta.env.VITE_ALGOLIA_SEARCH
  );

  watchEffect(() => {
    const index = searchClient.initIndex(unref(indexName));
    try{
      ...
    }
  })

  return results;
}
```

Comment: Ah that's brilliant thank you! I'm still new to watchEffect(), but is there a good reason to use that over watch() in this instance?

Comment: Took me a while to get used to `watchEffect()` too. I now prefer it when I know I want to watch all properties anyway and need an eager/immediate watcher, but don't need the old value or a deep watcher. This seems to be the most common use-case for watchers, so`watchEffect` basically communicates that you are dealing with such a general watcher, while reading more compact and saving you some of the busy-work. But there is nothing wrong with always using `watch` either, so pick the one you are more comfortable with.

Comment: Oh, and if the answer helped you, please consider leaving an upvote and/or marking it as the accepted answer. It is a bit silly, but it is how the site works.